# Error while opening order in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, order-summary

I am getting this [Error](https://prnt.sc/opk5nk) when i open order in magento admin panel https://prnt.sc/opk7u3

Comment: The order which you are trying to view has paypal payment method?

Comment: @Mitro not paypal but Some other paymen gateway

Comment: if your are using third party payment gateway then check it's config.xml has title parameter declared or not

Comment: @mitro i am using rave payment gateway. I checked its config.xml it has title parameter in it

Comment: then you have to dig into the code by backtrace

Comment: @Mitro Hmm thats difficult as it is a third party plugin

Comment: Not that much difficutl to debug. It is fun to debug the code in magento. Isn't it?

Comment: @mitro when i add <substitution> tag before <title>, it works, but in frontend the payment gateway name doesnot displayed it comes blank

Comment: Can anybody help. i am still stuck

Comment: Did you tried by disabling current payment method?